# How to solve OutOfMemoryError using LayerDrawable

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, out-of-memory

**Error:**

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:618)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:593)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:445)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:775)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1968)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:677)
at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:542)
at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:315)
at app.Main.GridActivity.initaliseLevel(GridActivity.java:245)
at app.Main.GridActivity.load_player_settings(GridActivity.java:180)
at app.Main.GridActivity.onResume(GridActivity.java:79)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1158)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4607)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2448)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2486)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2000)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The images are set by:

```
ImageButton b0 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton00);
Resources r = getResources();
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.imagetwo);
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
b0.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

From reading other answers, I gathered that the images need to be recycled after use. Is this the best option? If so how can a LayerDrawable be converted to a bitmap, so it can be recycled?

Comment: what is the dimensions (width x height) of the image you're trying to load?

Comment: There are about 25 layerDrawables all 175x175px and consisting of 2-3 layers

Comment: I am getting something similar. Fairly small images. If I comment out all but one image, no problem, but anything else crashes it. There is opacity settings on the first image... not sure if that is causing this?

Comment: Are you testing in an emulator?  If so, how big is your "Max VM application heap size," and can you increase it to figure out how much memory your program is actually using?

Comment: I was testing using s3 and emulator, I still haven't solved the issue. But I managed to decrease the amount of memory being leaked by setting the call back on my images to null and making sure I destroyed my adviews

Comment: set `b0=null` to mark it for GC.. then you may call System.gc().. see if it helps..

Comment: I am using an emulator and SGIII. It only crashes on the SGIII. I am declaring my images in XML. Even if I shrink the images to smaller size combined than the single that will show with no problem.

Comment: @userSeven7s unfortunately system.gc() doesn't guarantee that the GC actually runs see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#gc%28%29

Comment: ok.. How do you implement the GridView adpater..? can you add the adapter code..

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest > Application Attributes section there is a "Large Heap" setting, select your activity in the Application Nodes and then select "true" in the Heap Settings that did help me until i solved the leak.

and Also i have this in my activity:

```
private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view.getBackground() != null) {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    }
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
        }
        ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
    }
}

    @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.nameslayout));
    System.gc();
}
```

hop that helps

Comment: You sir rock! That got me to at least be able to load up my screen on my phone so that I can continue optimizing. Going to make sure I add your GC stuff as well since that looks good. Thank you!